# Почему при создании образа не получается установить нужные компоненты, а запуская контейнер они нормально устанавливаюся?

Tags: docker

Пытаюсь создать образ для тестов. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Мой `Dockerfile`

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y git

#apache2 mysql-server php php-mysql --fix-missing
```

При выполнении получаю ошибку

```
55.72 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     RUN apt-get update
   5 |     RUN apt-get upgrade -y
   6 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y git
   7 |      
   8 |     #apache2 mysql-server php php-mysql --fix-missing
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Ок. Допустим и правда не хватает `--fix-missing`

`Dockerfile`

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y git --fix-missing

#apache2 mysql-server php php-mysql --fix-missing
```

получаю

```
88.10 Errors were encountered while processing:
88.10  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
88.10  git
88.14 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.5-0_2.5.16%2bdfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
88.14 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libssh/libssh-4_0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
88.14 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-common_2.5.16%2bdfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
88.14 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     RUN apt-get update
   5 |     RUN apt-get upgrade -y
   6 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y git --fix-missing
   7 |      
   8 |     #apache2 mysql-server php php-mysql --fix-missing
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git --fix-missing" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Однако если в `Dockerfile` только это

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04
```

и на получившемся образе я запускаю контейнер и ввожу команды

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y git
```

То всё устанавливается без проблем.

*Вопрос*:**Почему?**

Comment: Почистьте кэши докера наверное

Comment: Попробуйте запускать `docker build --no-cache --network=host .`